# Overriding Makefile command line parameter, used in `ifeq`

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

My Makefile optionally receives a command line parameter called `COMPILE` which I want to override on the Makefile script itself.

According to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html), I've tried: `override COMPILE=gcc`.
However, `COMPILE` is used in the condition of an `ifeq` and setting `COMPILE` this way does not affect the first Make pass when conditionals are evaluated.

```
override COMPILE=gcc 

ifeq ($(COMPILE), gcc)
    ... I never get here...
else
    ... Always here ...
endif
```

Is there a way to properly override a Make parameter which is used in conditionals?

Comment: Works for me. Event without `override` directive.

Comment: Which version of Make are you using? And if you're hard-coding `COMPILE`, why do you make anything conditional on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Chnossos answer gave me the clue - **look for the whitespace**.
The problem was not with the space in "`ifeq ($(COMPILE), gcc)`", but in a trailing space on "`override COMPILE=gcc_`".  (underscore denotes where the space was).

After removing the trailing space after `=gcc`, everything works as expected.